# mysqli_query insert not generating any response, the connection is working, but no data is inserted

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

This is the code in my PHP script on a very basic html page with a form. I have tried every possible variation of single quotes, double, single and double for the values. I didn't get any response at all. I have tested to make sure the connection is made, but nothing is inserted in the DB. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
// Check our connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    print_r("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

     // Insert our data
    $query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO 'contacts' ('id','name', 'company', 'email', 'comment')  VALUES ('','$name', '$company', '$email', '$comment')", $con);
    $result = ($query); 


    if( $result )
    {
        print_r('Success');
    }
    else
    {
        print_r('Query Failed');
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your order is inverted, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php.

connection first, then query.

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

You also incorrectly used single quotes around the column names; those should be backticks; [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks?lq=1).

Additionally you should never pass user input directly to SQL. This is how injections occur. You should look into using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        print_r("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
}
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ 
     $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);  
     $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['company']);  
     $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);  
     $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['comment']);
     // Insert our data
     $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `contacts` (`name`, `company`, `email`, `comment`)  VALUES ('$name', '$company', '$email', '$comment')"); 
     if($query) {
          print_r('Success');
     } else {
          print_r('Query Failed');
     }
     mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: If downvoting, post why (current standings 2 DVs; 2 UVs).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use apostrophe (`'`) for your table and column name. Remove the apostrophe in your contacts table. You can use backticks (`) for column names.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO contacts (id, name, company, email, comment)  
                                     VALUES ('','$name', '$company', '$email', '$comment')");
```

You are also prone to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), so use [`*_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);  
$company = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['company']);  
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);  
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['comment']);
```

While you are at it, using `mysqli_*` API, you might want to check on [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: All quotes/apostrophes should be removed from columns. Quotes are for strings. Backticks are for columns.